# Fabric returnCode with fabric.tasks.execute

Tags: python, fabric

I have a python script that uses Fabric api. The problem is that am unable to get the return code the command launched on remote server.

I know i can get the return code with `.return_code` which work fine if I run `local` commands but not with multiple remote hosts using `fabric.tasks.execute` eg: `execute(self.run,command=task,hosts=self.HOSTS)`

Below is the extract of the class code:

```
def execs(self,task):
        with settings(warn_only=True):
            if (self.getMode() is "local"):
                return self.run(task)
            else:
                return execute(self.run,command=task,hosts=self.HOSTS)


def run(self,command):
        with settings(warn_only=True):
            if (self.getMode() is "local"):
                return local(command,True)
            if self.isSudo():
                return sudo(command,pty=False)
            return run(command,pty=False)

def dir_exists(self,directory):
        '''Check if directory exists'''
        if ((self.execs("test -d %s" % (directory))).return_code == 0):
            return True
        else:
            warn("Directory doesnot exists")
            return False

def dir_ensure(self,destination = None , user =None,group = None, permissions =None,recursive= False):
        '''Ensures a directory is created'''
        if (destination is None):
            warn("Destination of directory must be specified")
            return False
        if (self.dir_exists(destination)):
            warn("Destination folder already exists; Just setting permissions")
            self.dir_setAttr(destination,user,group,permissions,recursive)
        else:
            self.execs("mkdir -p %s" % (destination))
            self.dir_setAttr(destination,user,group,permissions,recursive)
```

When i run the code:

`myCooker.dir_ensure("/tmp/tototoot",user="k.sewnundun",group="k.sewnundun",permissions="777",recursive=True)`

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    myCooker.dir_ensure("/tmp/tototoot",user="k.sewnundun",group="k.sewnundun",permissions="777",recursive=True)
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/cooker.py", line 234, in dir_ensure
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/cooker.py", line 210, in dir_exists
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'return_code'
```

But if i change the `.exec` to `.run` in methods `dir_ensure` and `dir_exists` and set `env.host_string` am able to get the return code of remote command but the issue is am able to pass only one host **which is not the result wanted**.

How do i **get the return code using the `.exec` in method `dir_exists`** or maybe a better approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch out, `fabric`'s `execute` returns `dict`!

From docs:

Returns: a dictionary mapping host strings to the given task’s return value for that host’s execution run. For example, execute(foo, hosts=['a', 'b']) might return {'a': None, 'b': 'bar'} if foo returned nothing on host a but returned 'bar' on host b.

Therefore, you will find you error code in `result_dict[host].return_code`.

You also have to return output from `fabric`'s `run` function, but you do that: `return run(command,pty=False)`. Without that you would find `None` in dictionary.

Hope it helps.